# Is it valid to pass a compound literal into a function?

Tags: c, struct, compound-literals

I have a struct type as a parameter and need to pass it into function.

The entire code is below:

```c
void insert(struct node *newt) {
    struct node *node = head, *prev = NULL;
    while (node != NULL && node->data < newt->data) {
        prev = node;
        node = node->next;
    }
    newt->next = node;
    if (prev == NULL)
        head = newt;
    else
        prev->next = newt;
}
void print(){
    struct  node *tmp = head;
    while(tmp){
        printf("%d->",tmp->data);
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
int main(){
    /*
    * Experiment for naive-insert
    */
    for(int i = 1; i < 4; i++){
        insert(&(struct node){.data = i, .next = NULL});
    }
    //insert(&(struct node){.data = 1, .next = NULL});
    //insert(&(struct node){.data = 2, .next = NULL});
    //insert(&(struct node){.data = 3, .next = NULL});
    print();

}
```

If I call insert in for loop, it will print .....->3->3->3....(can't stop)

But if I just replace for loop with

```cpp
insert(&(struct node){.data = 1, .next = NULL});
insert(&(struct node){.data = 2, .next = NULL});
insert(&(struct node){.data = 3, .next = NULL});
```

it will act normally. I wondering what's going on with my for-loop version code.

Comment: Those two pieces of code aren't exactly the same with regards to the `data` field, which starts from 0 in the loop code, but starts from 1 in the non-loop code. Then, in your `insert` function, you check that value via `node->data < newt->data`. Perhaps your problem is actually there.

Comment: I just check them, data field is noting to do with infinite 3 happening.

Comment: You pass the address of a local struct and you save that address as link. If you want to have persistent nodes, you should make sure that the nodes are actually different and live as long as the list lives.  You could do that by `malloc`/ `calloc`ing the nodes, for example. Another possibility is to create an array of node structs and insert the elements.

Comment: I think you'll find that both versions are wrong - both have the same undefined behaviour but one of them just happens to appear to "work". In both cases those `struct node` pointers passed to the function are out of scope as soon as the function exits. You must not store the pointer values and use them after that.

Comment: @kaylum: There's no scope issue, at least not at function level. (There might be one of the loop scope.) The struct is passed "upwards". But I think the variant in the loop re-uses the same space to create a temporary object and creates an circular list . But I agree that the other variant just happens to work. The compiler is probably free to re-use the same space here, too.

Comment: @MOehm Yeah, "scope" is probably not the right technical term. I was struggling to get the right by the book wording for that. It's an unusual way to pass a struct pointer in (at least to me).

Comment: Well it is a scope issues, which is the *storage duration* issue of the compound-literal only having a lifetime within the block-scope of the loop. Individually set, then its scope is `main()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Edit: In the initial draft, I was wrong about the nature of the storage created with compouind literals. Jonathan Leffler's comments and Eric Postpischil's answer are spot on and have proven my initial point wrong. An alternative to creating linked lists I suggested is valid, mut no longer needed. I've amended my anser.]]

The code in your loop is equivalent to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    struct node tmp = {.data = i, .next = NULL};

    insert(&tmp);
}
```

The compiler creates a temporary object and passes its address to your list function. That temporary object is only valid in the loop body and goes out of scope directly after insertion. Accessing the invalidated objects after the loop via pointers in the list when you print the list is Undefined Behaviour.)

The code without a loop is equivalent to:

```
struct node tmp1 = {.data = 1, .next = NULL};
struct node tmp2 = {.data = 2, .next = NULL};
struct node tmp3 = {.data = 3, .next = NULL};

insert(&tmp1);
insert(&tmp2);
insert(&tmp3);
```

Your linked list is good as long as the `tmpX`variables don't go out of scope.

Comment: The three separate `insert()` calls have no undefined behaviour.  Those three compound literals are separate — they go out of scope at the end of the calling function (`main()`).  With the looped call, the compound literal goes out of scope on each iteration — the list is pointing at invalid memory (it is coincidence that it looks like the last entry).  That is lots of undefined behaviour.  For safety, the `insert()` function should make a copy of the structure that is passed to it (dynamic memory allocation).  You then need a `delete()` function to release the data in the list, too.

Comment: Are objects created by compound literals guaranteed to be different? But my answer fails to say that the object goes out of scope when the loop body terminates. I also agree that allocating each node on the heap is safer, but clearly that is what OP tries to avoid.

Comment: It depends on scope, but in the three-call case, yes.  See C11 [§6.5.2.5 Compound literals](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.5), especially ¶5 which says in part: _If the compound literal occurs outside the body of a function, the object has static storage duration; otherwise, it has automatic storage duration associated with the enclosing block._

Comment: I see. Thanks for clarifying that. (If you don't take the addresses of compound literals, which I think isn't very common, they just behave as one expects. Which also means that one doesn't think about them much, I guess.)

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to initialise new nodes in a linked list with temp values - this is not going to end well!!

```cpp
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        insert(&(struct node){.data = i, .next = NULL});
    }
```

What's clearly happening here is that the compiler has recycled the same memory on the stack to generate the temporary variable. In effect the previous node is the same as the next one, so you end up with the same node pointing to itself (whose last value is 2).

You can see this by adding the following line at the start of insert:

```cpp
    printf("%p\n", newt);
```

You should really be using malloc instead of doing this.

Answer (score 2):

C 2018 6.5.2.5 5 says a compound literal inside a function has automatic storage duration:

> … If the compound literal occurs outside the body of a function, the object has static storage duration; otherwise, it has automatic storage duration associated with the enclosing block.

This means that storage is reserved for the compound literal from the time program execution reaches its declaration until execution of the enclosing block ends.

When the code is written:

```
int main(void)
{
   …
    insert(&(struct node){.data = 1, .next = NULL});
    insert(&(struct node){.data = 2, .next = NULL});
    insert(&(struct node){.data = 3, .next = NULL});
    print();
}
```

then the enclosing block is the `{ … }` that forms the body of `main`, and the compound literals exist until execution of `main` ends. So they still exist (meaning storage is reserved for them, for each of them) while `print` is executing).

In this code:

```
for(int i = 1; i < 4; i++){
        insert(&(struct node){.data = i, .next = NULL});
    }
```

the enclosing block is the `{ … }` that is the body of the for loop. Execution of that block ends each time the `for` loop iterates. So, when the `print` routine is later called, none of these compound literals exists anymore (storage is not reserved for any of them, and it has likely been reused for each of them successively).